# Frequent disabling of my SMTP/Sendmail service by hostinger

Tags: sendmailr

I have a hosting at Hostinger and my mail id configured is being repeatedly disabled by the host informing me that spam mail is being forwarded from my id. I have changed my password number of times and activated my mail but after a few moments, it is again being disabled. Kindly guide as to how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when either system or users (recipients of the email) mark you email as spam.
So, avoid this:

1. Avoid sending mass emails especially to unverified list.
2. Install **Recaptcha** in all your contact forms and login forms.

Further, few smart advice would be:

1. Don’t write subject lines **ALL IN CAPS**.
2. Don’t make spelling mistakes.
3. Don’t plea with people to "**Open Me!**".
4. Don’t deceive readers with a false promise.
5. Don’t give away everything in your subject line.
6. Don’t use one word – like "**Hi!**" – as your subject line.
7. Skip the punctuation!!!
8. Don’t add "**Re:**" to your subject line to deceive readers.

Good luck!